# Is Cook's Distance a reliable way to find influential points?

Tags: regression, linear-model, outliers, anomaly-detection, cooks-distance

I used Cook's Distance to identify influential points on several datasets and found model performance doesn't improve at all after removing them. So I wonder if Cook's Distance is a reliable way to remove influential points to improve linear model's performance. If it is, what did I do wrong in the following sample code? If it is not, please suggest reliable ways for remove influential points for linear models.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read data
boston_dataset = load_boston()
boston = pd.DataFrame(boston_dataset.data, columns=boston_dataset.feature_names) # shape: (506, 13)

m = ols('LSTAT ~ CRIM+ZN+INDUS+CHAS+NOX+RM+AGE+DIS+RAD+TAX+PTRATIO+B', boston).fit()
infl = m.get_influence()
sm_fr = infl.summary_frame()
plt.stem(np.arange(len(sm_fr)), sm_fr.cooks_d, markerfmt=' ')
print(len(np.where(sm_fr.cooks_d>4/506)[0])) # standard threshold gives 42 outliers
# 42
print(np.where(sm_fr.cooks_d>0.12)[0]) # the outlier with the highest distance
# [410]

# compare the performance of models with and without the 401th data point
# create train and test datasets without the outlier data point
boston_train, boston_test = train_test_split(boston.drop(boston.index[401]), test_size=0.2, random_state=100)

# train linear regression model with the outlier in the trian dataset
boston_train2 = boston_train.append(boston.iloc[401])
X_train = boston_train2.drop('LSTAT', axis=1)
y_train = boston_train2.LSTAT.values

X_test = boston_test.drop('LSTAT', axis=1)
y_test = boston_test.LSTAT.values
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
# (405, 12) (405,) (101, 12) (101,)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
yp_train = lr.predict(X_train)
yp_test = lr.predict(X_test)
print('TRAIN-RMSE: {:,.5f}'.format(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, yp_train))))
print('TEST-RMSE: {:,.5f}'.format(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, yp_test))))
# TRAIN-RMSE: 4.29493
# TEST-RMSE: 3.65956

# train linear regression model without the outlier in the trian dataset
X_train = boston_train.drop('LSTAT', axis=1)
y_train = boston_train.LSTAT.values

X_test = boston_test.drop('LSTAT', axis=1)
y_test = boston_test.LSTAT.values
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
# (404, 12) (404,) (101, 12) (101,)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
yp_train = lr.predict(X_train)
yp_test = lr.predict(X_test)
print('TRAIN-RMSE: {:,.5f}'.format(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, yp_train))))
print('TEST-RMSE: {:,.5f}'.format(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, yp_test))))
# TRAIN-RMSE: 4.29798
# TEST-RMSE: 3.65681

# 3.65956/3.65681 = 1.0007520215707133 => 0.07% difference in performance
```

[image]

Comment: Influential points don't necessarily harm a model.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the kind reply. Are there any methods which can identify outlier/influential points which can harm a model?

Comment: In principle, yes.  They require you to specify--quantitatively--how to measure the goodness of a model.  You can then systematically remove points (alone or in small groups) to assess how much they change the goodness.  "Goodness" shouldn't necessarily be related to an internal measure like $R^2.$ It could be a measure of how well the model performs when applied to a separate dataset, for instance.

Comment: @whuber Suppose I use MSE to measure the goodness of a linear regression model like in the above sample code. Could you name a few reliable methods to identify potential data points which need to remove?

Comment: (Tongue planted firmly in cheek) Just remove all the points with the largest absolute residuals.

Comment: I must repeat my first comment: removal should not be automatic.  There is no universal criterion for *needing* to remove data.  It all depends on the data and what you need to achieve with them. Often the best one can do is perform a full analysis with and without the influential points and, if the results differ, report both sets of results and otherwise assert the analysis is robust.

Comment: The robust regression function 'glmrob' from package robustbase has a weights.on.x argument which allows you to weight observations inversely proportional to their leverage. Useful way to assess the impact of outlying observations without having to remove them